# Learning languages like javascript ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been doing some development where i just couldn't stick to PHP, i needed to use Javascript or whatever. Whenever i needed to use a different language i just searched for some snippets or what ever and i would copy paste.

Have you guys got any tips for me how to get more experienced with an language?

websites with tutorials or anything like that ?

i really want to get into web development, but i'm stuck at PHP since we don't get more languages on my web development course.

p.s. not sure if this is the right place to post this, but i thought lets give it a go, correct me if this isn't the right place

Answer (score 1):

There are many places from where you can learn javascript, jquery, ajax etc.
These are two of them:
http://www.w3schools.com/
https://www.youtube.com/

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is get yourself a free course from http://www.codecademy.com/
get yourself busy with reading about the languages you want to know, get some books and the most important, Try to make things, dont stop if you counter some problems, You can only learn from your mistakes.

I won't follow youtube guides tho, I am not a fan of them, but that is personal tho:)

Edit: I did use codecademy.com for Python, it helps alot! give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ a lot to help me keep up-to-date with new technologies.  They have really good courses and are all completely free.

Another good resource that I had used in the past is http://www.lynda.com/.  They have some free courses and some are paid for more advanced topics.

I would caution a little about [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com), as a lot of the videos can be hard to follow and more confusing to persons who are new to the subject that is being discussed.  However, there are some out there that are really very helpful.

If you want more of a structured class format, then https://www.edx.org/ has full courses from some of the top schools, including MIT, Harvard, Berkeley, and many more.  They also have courses from top partners like Microsoft, IEEE, W3C, and Linux.  These are typically full courses from the actual university and, in some cases, you'll follow along with the students that are enrolled in the course for that semester.  It's very well done, and completely free.  *There is a small fee if you want a verified certificate, but learning is always completely free.*

If you like the class format and learn well that way, MIT has a lot of full courses available online for free at http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm.  There's a huge course list.  Here's an example from their [Electrical Engineering and Computer Science program](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/)

These are all resources that I either currently use or have used in the past and I highly recommend them.  Even though I have been programming for 20 years and have been a professional software engineer for 17 years, I try to stay as up-to-date as possible on all of the latest technologies so I can continue to be relevant in this fast-paced world.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners, I recomend: http://coursesweb.net/ (has free lessons, code snippets and scripts) and http://www.w3schools.com/